# Prove that Big-O is transitive by relation. What does it mean by 'by relation'?

Tags: algorithms, proof-techniques

Prove $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and $g(n) = O(h(n))$, then $f(n) = O(h(n))$.

The question is

> Prove that Big-O is transitive **by relation.**

What does it mean by `by relation`??

Comment: Where did you see that sentence? Can you credit the source where you saw that and provide some context?  If it's from your instructor, have you tried asking them?  If it's from a textbook, do they define "relation"?  Help us help you by editing the question to provide us as much information as possible.

Comment: Sounds like a dubious translation from a different language, or a phrase from a non-native speaker. My guess at the correct version is *as a relation* instead of *by relation*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f(n)=O(g(n)) implies f(n) <= c<sub>1</sub>*g(n)
g(n)=O(h(n)) implies g(n) <= c<sub>2</sub>*h(n)
therefore, 

f(n) <= c<sub>1</sub>*c<sub>2</sub>*h(n) = c<sub>3</sub>*h(n)

f(n) <= c<sub>3</sub>*h(n) implies f(n)=O(h(n))

Comment: Confused about why this has been accepted. It doesn't answer the question at all, since the question is what does "by relation" mean, not how to prove transitivity of big-O.

Comment: relation means the mathematical term "relation". "by relation" means that for a relation R, if (a,b) belongs to R, (b,c) belongs to R, then (a,c) will also belong to R. And here (f(n), g(n)) belongs to R, (g(n),h(n)) belongs to R, hence (f(n), h(n)) also belongs to R.

Comment: No, that's what transitivity means. As a native speaker, I would say "prove that big-O is transitive _as a_ relation" if I wanted to tell somebody "prove that the relation $\{f,g\mid f=O(g)\}$ is transitive". But, in any case, the question asks what "by relation" means and your answer doesn't say anything at all about that.